# How can I render a external component by calling a function like Component.show() in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, antd

Let's supose I have a Toast (or Modal, or whateaver) component, and I want to render it doing something like:

```
return (
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Toast.show()}>
      <Text>Press</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

I don't want nothing else in my App component, just the import of the Toast, and the return with the button that calls the Toast rendering. Without, any conditional or state on my App component function, or any {Toast} (or {isVisible && } inside its return.

I know that is possible, because I already seen libraries like AntDesign (for React JS), which has the message component, that works like a function, you just calls message.success() in whateaver part of the code, and a Message is displayed in your screen, what should I do in my Toast component to get a similar result?

Comment: They would use portals https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal#createportal to attach it to the `document.body` or some other global container in the DOM

Comment: In [react-native-toast-message](https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message/blob/main/src/Toast.tsx); The toast component creates a ref for showing/hiding the component. They then create a function for grabbing the ref, and call the ref

Comment: They store the refs outside of the react lifecycle, so it seems hacky to me. I think you would have an easier time just creating a imperative ref for your component and then calling show/hide on that ref

Answer (score 1):

I dived into the source of antd to see how they're achieving this. The jist of what they're doing is:

1. They create a message component, in your case `Toast` component
2. They use `ReactDOM.createPortal()` to specify a new location for the component.
3. They create a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) and use that to create a new [root](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot), which they then used to render the portal to.

```js
const Toast = ({msg}) => {
  return <h1>Toast: {msg}</h1>;
}
const ToastPortal = (props) => ReactDOM.createPortal(<Toast {...props} />, document.body)

const showToast = (msg) => {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  ReactDOM.createRoot(fragment).render(<ToastPortal msg={msg} />);
}

const App = () => <button onClick={() => showToast("Hello world!")}>
  Show Toast
</button>;

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I was trying to achieve this, I took a look into this createPortal(). But I notice that it renders a component on the DOM, and as I'm in a React Native project, it won't be possible to me. Maybe there's something similiar as the DOM in Native, I don't know. I did some researches and I find out that maybe I could get what I want by using some libraries, but I wanted to do it without adding anything else in my project. Would you know how to get the same result in React Native?